# Splunk: Combining multiple chart queries to get a single table

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation, splunk-dashboard

As on today we have two queries that are running

1st query: **Count of api grouped by apiName and status**

```
index=aws* api.metaData.pid="myAppName"
| rename api.p as apiName
| chart count BY apiName "api.metaData.status"
| multikv forceheader=1
| table apiName success error NULL
```

which displays a table something like shown below

```
=====================================
| apiName|| success || error || NULL|
=====================================
| Test1  || 10      || 20    || 0   |
| Test2  || 10      || 20    || 0   |
| Test3  || 10      || 20    || 0   |
| Test4  || 10      || 20    || 0   |
| Test5  || 10      || 20    || 0   |
| Test6  || 10      || 20    || 0   |
```

2nd query : **latency of api grouped by apiName**

```
index=aws* api.metaData.pid="myAppName" 
| rename api.p as apiName 
| rename api.measures.tt as Response_Time 
| chart min(Response_Time) as RT_fastest max(Response_Time) as RT_slowest by apiName
| table apiName RT_fastest RT_slowest
```

which displays a table something like below

```
======================================
| apiName || RT_fastest || RT_slowest|
======================================
| Test1   || 141        || 20        |
| Test2   || 10         || 20        |
| Test3   || 10         || 20        |
| Test4   ||  0         || 20        |
| Test5   || 10         || 20        |
| Test6   || 10         || 20        |
```

**Question:**

If you see the above tables, both tables are grouped with **apiName**. Is there a way to combine these queries so that i get a single result something like this

|=================================================================|
| apiName || success || error || NULL || RT_fastest|| RT_slowest  |
================================================================= |
| Test1   || 10      || 20.   || 20.  || 20.       || 20.         |
| Test2   || 10      || 20.   || 20.  || 20.       || 20.         |
| Test3   || 10      || 20.   || 20.  || 20.       || 20.         |
| Test4   || 10      || 20.   || 20.  || 20.       || 20.         |
| Test5   || 10      || 20.   || 20.  || 20.       || 20.         |
| Test6   || 10      || 20.   || 20.  || 20.       || 20.         |

I could not find any documentation regarding combining multiple chart query into one. Could someone please help me with this. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge here is the two queries use different groupings - apiName and status in query1 and apiName alone in query2.  Simply combining the two `chart` commands is not possible.

We can, however, append the second query to the first and then merge the results.  Try this:

```
index=aws* api.metaData.pid="myAppName"
| rename api.p as apiName
| chart count BY apiName "api.metaData.status"
| multikv forceheader=1
| table apiName success error NULL
| append [ search index=aws* api.metaData.pid="myAppName" 
  | rename api.p as apiName 
  | rename api.measures.tt as Response_Time 
  | chart min(Response_Time) as RT_fastest max(Response_Time) as RT_slowest by apiName
  | table apiName RT_fastest RT_slowest ]
| stats values(*) as * by apiName
| table apiName success error NULL RT_fastest RT_slowest
```

Comment: I see the error: 

Error in 'table' command: Invalid argument: 'RT_fastest=146.000'
The search job has failed due to an error. You may be able view the job in the Job Inspector.

Comment: I left out a pipe.  Try the updated answer.